# How to access js event object in a super type that is called from a subtype?

Tags: javascript, inheritance, prototype, dom-events

I write different parsers of the HTML context of an event in a webpage.

The basic structure goes like this:

registering the event and link it to a parser function.

```
elem.addEventListener(
    'click',
    (e) => {
        let parser = new UiResultsItemInfoParser(e);
        eventInfo = parser.evntInfo;
        submitEvnt(eventInfo);
    }
);
```

`UiResultsItemInforParser` is a sub-type of a super type called `EvntParser` and `e` obviously is the event object.

`EvntParser` looks like this:

```
function EvntParser (e) {
    this._evntInfo = {};
    this._evntInfo.time = e.timeStamp.toString();
    this._evntInfo.type = 'event';
}

EvntParser.prototype = {
    set evntInfo(e) {
        this._evntInfo.time = e.timeStamp.toString();
        this._evntInfo.type = 'event';
    },
    get evntInfo() {
        return JSON.stringify(this._evntInfo);
    }
};
```

`UiResultsItemInforParser` is derived from `EvntParser` and looks like this:

```
function UiResultsItemInfoParser(e) {
    EvntParser.call(this, e);
}

UiResultsItemInfoParser.prototype = new EvntParser();
UiResultsItemInfoParser.prototype.constructor = UiResultsItemInfoParser;
```

Unfortunately, I get `TypeError: e is undefined` for the line `this._evntInfo.time = e.timeStamp.toString();` in `EvntParser` when the event is triggered and a new `UiResultsItemInfoParser` object is created in `addEventListener`.

Why is that and how can I fix it in a way that `EvntParser` has access to the event object during object creation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This

```
UiResultsItemInfoParser.prototype = new EvntParser();
```

is an opt-repeated anti-pattern, and the root of your issue. `EvntParser` expects an argument and assumes it was given it (`this._evntInfo.time = e.timeStamp.toString()`), so it fails when you do the above.

Instead:

```
UiResultsItemInfoParser.prototype = Object.create(EvntParser.prototype);
```

That creates an object that has `EvntParser.prototype` as its prototype, but *without* calling `EvntParser`. (Then your next line, which is exactly right, fixes `constructor` on the resulting object.)

Later, you're doing the right thing by doing `EvntParser.call(this, e);` in your subclass constructor. So it's really just the one line.

---

Since you're using arrow functions, you must be working in an ES2015 environment. That means you can use the new `class` syntax, which does all this fiddly hooking things up for you:

```
class EvntParser {
    constructor(e) {
        this._evntInfo = {};
        this._evntInfo.time = e.timeStamp.toString();
        this._evntInfo.type = 'event';
    }
    set evntInfo(e) {
        this._evntInfo.time = e.timeStamp.toString();
        this._evntInfo.type = 'event';
    }
    get evntInfo() {
        return JSON.stringify(this._evntInfo);
    }
}

class UiResultsItemInfoParser extends EvntParser {
}
```

Note how you don't even need to define a constructor in `UiResultsItemInfoParser`; when you don't, the JavaScript engine defines one for you that calls `super` with all the arguments it receives.

---

Side note: This:

```
this._evntInfo = {};
this._evntInfo.time = e.timeStamp.toString();
this._evntInfo.type = 'event';
```

can also be written

```
this._evntInfo = {
    time: e.timeStamp.toString(),
    type: 'event'
};
```

if you like (even before ES2015). Exactly the same object is created.

Comment: Thanks! Really interesting though, that I got the pattern from a brand new reference and beginners book (https://www.amazon.de/JavaScript-Fortgeschrittene-Objektorientierung-funktionale-Programmierung/dp/3836238381). That is really a shame. (Side note: I used pseudo-class notation just to get a feeling for the prototype logic which I do not know so much, but thx anyway!)

Comment: @CutúChiqueño: Oh, that **is** a shame. If the book has a website, maybe you could report a bug... Well, as I say, everything else was right. :-)